# How to transfer file from Windows to Mainframe using FTP or script?

Tags: ftp, mainframe

We would like to transfer a file everyday from a Shared location to remote location.

I was informed to use following script:

```
ASCII
QUOTE SITE RECFM=FB LRECL=750 BLKSIZE=23250 FILE=SEQ CYL PRI=50 SEC=20
PUT filename ‘filename(+1)'
BYE
```

Also, was recommended to use MOVEit Freely 5.5.0.0 – Secure FTP client.

Is the script above has to be written in Mainframe or in .dat file ?

Comment: Those are ftp commands. `ASCII` means the transfer is in ascii, not binary mode. `QUOTE` is short for `QUOTE PASV`. `SITE RECFM=FB LRECL=750 BLKSIZE=23250 FILE=SEQ CYL PRI=50 SEC=20` is site specific commands. `PUT filename` means send the file. `BYE` means disconnect.

Comment: The script should be written in format understood by MOVEit Freely. It is ascii text format. And stored on the client side where MOVEit Freely is being used.

Comment: Thanks alvit. We are trying to send a file using Moveit Freely : FTPS -e:implicit -a -natpasv -d -user:xxxxxx -password:yyyyyyyy -z –s:WareSuppPROD.citation 167.xxx.xxx.xx 990

Comment: However, not sure on where the script has to be written in txt file. FTPS script in my previous comment and script from my question...

Comment: The script name from your previous comment is `WareSuppPROD.citation`. This file is where those questions you posted should be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using text editor, put the ftp commands, one command per line.

```
ASCII
QUOTE SITE RECFM=FB LRECL=750 BLKSIZE=23250 FILE=SEQ CYL PRI=50 SEC=20
PUT filename ‘filename(+1)'
BYE
```

Let's pretend the script filename you  made is `send.txt`, you can then run the command `ftps` like:

```
ftps -s:send.txt hostname
```

Comment: Thanks alot, alvits.     We successfully transferred the file today after some tweaking.

Comment: We had to remove (+1) in the command PUT filename ‘filename(+1)' and it worked like charm !!